# jira mobile connect not creating an issue

Tags: ios, ios6, jira-mobile-connect

I integrated Jira Mobile Connect into my iPhone application. When I click on send button in `feedbackViewController`, it shows an alert that your feedback is received. But in real, it does not create an issue in Jira. Even when I click on any of the feedback I created, it shows me this alert.

[image: Jira Mobile Connect issue]

It has been more than a week that I first created a feedback and is still shown in transit. I don't find much discussion about this issue on Internet and not a single answer to this issue. Is there anybody who had the same problem?

**EDIT**
I enabled `JMC_DEBUG` and then ran my application. Along with other lines I saw this.

> [JMCTransportOperation connection:didFailWithError:] Request failed:
>   request body stream exhausted.

```
URL: https://objectlounge.atlassian.net/rest/jconnect/1.0/issue/create?project=RIDESHARE&apikey=8418bedf-ef8b-431e-8f3b-7ba2f1d91fa4, response code: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Enabling `JMC_DEBUG` helped me to get to the root of the problem. The error I got in console is shown in my question. The problem was `Jira mobile connect user` did not have permission for creating an issue. Giving him a permission to create an issue in the project solved the problem.

**UPDATE** : To enable `JMC_DEBUG` in xcode,
 go to `Targets` in your project.
 Click `Build Settings`.
 search for `Preprocessor Macros` and add this value `JMC_DEBUG=1` in Debug section.